How do I set a token for maven_install rule in bazel?
I'm trying to download a maven artifact using bazel with maven_install. Artifactory requires a token which I have and confirmed it works via: curl -vvv --oauth2-bearer token url. I can see the Authorization: Bearer token header set in the request so thats what I need to replicate in Bazel. The only option I can find is auth_patterns but that doesn't work afaik for maven_install. Is there any way to tell bazel to use a token for this specific artifactory repo?
